# ACS characters not working in putty even with export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1

Tags: c, ncurses, terminfo

I am developing an ncurses application myself in C. The problem is that putty displays alternative character set characters like ACS_VLINE as letters. My locale is

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

and I have set

```
export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1
```

I have also set putty to UTF-8 and tried different fonts. The characters display fine on the tty on the actual machine so I think the issue is with putty. I have also tried linking ncursesw instead of ncurses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a combination of things.  The recommended `TERM` for PuTTY is ["putty"](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-putty), but due to inertia, most people use ["xterm"](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm).  The line-drawing support in the xterm terminal description is different from PuTTY's assumptions because [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html) supports [luit](http://invisible-island.net/luit/luit.html), which has some limitations with the way the alternate character set is managed (see [Debian Bug report #254316: 
ncurses-base: workaround for screen's handling of register sgr0 isn't quite right](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=254316)).

If you use `infocmp` to compare, you may see these lines which deal with the alternate character set:

```
    acsc: '``aaffggiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~', '``aaffggjjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~'.
    enacs: NULL, '\E(B\E)0'.
    rmacs: '\E(B', '^O'.
    smacs: '\E(0', '^N'.
```

VT100s can have two character sets "designated", referred to as G0 and G1:

- The "xterm" line-drawing works by changing the designation of G0 between the ASCII and line-drawing characters,
- the "putty" line-drawing works by designating ASCII in G0 and line-drawing in G1 and switching between the two with the shift-in/shift-out control characters.

Although both are VT100-compatible, the xterm scheme does not work with PuTTY.  Because of the tie-in with `luit`, the normal terminal description for `xterm` will not change (unless it proves possible to modify `luit` to solve the problem for its users), so a workaround is needed for users of PuTTY:

- use a different terminal description as recommended, e.g., `TERM=putty`.  PuTTY's settings dialog lets you set environment variables to pass to the remote machine.

  This has the drawback that some systems do not have the full ncurses terminal database installed, due to "size" (it is 6.8Mb on my local machine).  Also, `TERM` may not be on the list of allowed ssh environment variables.
- you can compile your own terminfo entry with ncurses' tic, e.g.,

  `cat >foo <<"EOF"
  xterm|my terminfo entry,
          enacs=\E(B\E)0,
          rmacs=^O,
          smacs=^N,
          use=xterm-new,
  EOF
  tic foo`
- use GNU screen.  It does its own fixes, and happens to compensate for PuTTY's problems.

Further reading

- [SCS – Select Character Set](http://vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/chapter3.html#SCS) (VT100 manual)
- [4.4 Character Set Selection (SCS)](http://vt100.net/docs/vt220-rm/chapter4.html) (VT220 manual)
- [The terminfo database is big—do I need all of that?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#big_terminfo) (ncurses FAQ)
- [Putty: login, execute command/change environment variable, and do NOT close the session](https://superuser.com/questions/708742/putty-login-execute-command-change-environment-variable-and-do-not-close-the)

Comment: Thank you. Using GNU screen or Tmux solves the problem.

Answer (score 7):

I want to make some additions. I faced same issue: many ncurses-based tools like `dialog`, `menuconfig` and `nconfig` from Linux kenrel sources, even `mc` is broken when built with ncurses (although `mc` is built using Slang on many OSes and not affected).

*Here is what happened*

ncurses uses `smacs` record from terminfo to switch to "alternative charset" and then it uses `acsc` to draw boxes. It sends `a` which is box-drawing character in alternative charset (ACS).
This is VT100 graphics.

Some terminal emulators nowadays do not support ACS when in UTF-8 because apps have ability to send real box-drawing codepoints.

There is unofficial capability `U8` (capital U!) in `terminfo` that tells ncurses: "Instead of ACS use real box-drawing codepoints."

I have this capability `infocmp -x xterm-utf` and for putty aswell, but not for `xterm`.

As you can read in `ncurses(3)` (https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html), `ncurses` is aware of Linux console and GNU screen (and tmux, which also uses `screen` as `TERM`) and always behave like if `U8` were set.

For other terminals that do not support ACS when in UTF, you can set `NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS`.

Unfortunatelly, ncurses is not aware of putty.

There is also `luit` that may convert ACS to Unicode points.

So, here is what we can do to run ncurses + putty in UTF-8:

- Use terminal with `U8#1` capability. This one is set for putty (btw, I suggest to use `putty-256color` instead). You can create your own entry with `U8#1` and `colors#256` and compile it with `tic -x`. Be carefull that mouse may not work on terminals that do not start with `xterm` (see `mouseinterval(3)`, BUGS section). This is why I do not use `putty` terminal. I suggest to copy `xterm-utf8`, add `colors#256`, compile and stay with it: it works perfectly with putty, mouse and utf8.
- You can set `NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS` in your profile.
- You can run `screen` or `tmux`: it will set `TERM` to `screen` and fix `ncurses`
- You can run `luit`: it will do all convertions for you.
- Since putty 0.71 you can ask putty to support ACS drawings even in UTF-8

  [image: Since putty 0.71 you can ask putty to support ACS drawings even in UTF-8]

Comment: tmux and the new putty setting are what fixed it for me. Thanks.